# SUM function with JOINED tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to determine the total dollar amount a customer has spent using SQL. I have two tables, Customers and Orders. Orders has a 'Total_Payment_Received' for each individual order. What I want is the sum of all "Total_Payment_Received"'s to be output, for a given CustomerID on the Customers table. I don't need to see all the individual orders, just the total amount of business they have done with us.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Example:

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Company_Name
      ,SUM(Orders.Total_Payment_Received)
  FROM Customers
  JOIN Orders ON Customers.CustomerID = Order.CustomerID
  WHERE Customers.LastModified BETWEEN '01/01/11 00:00:01' AND '05/15/11 11:59:59';
```

Comment: You just need to add a "GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Company_Name". And if you want to include customers without orders, you will need to do an outer join.

Answer (score 1):

- You need group by customer. I suppose a customer is identified by the (Primary Key) `CustomerID`, so use: `GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID`
- For dates it's better to use the standarized ISO format `'20110515'` or the `'2011-05-15'` format, so there is no ambiguity. When you are using something like `'01/05/11'`, it's not all clear if it's `01-May-2011` or `Jan-05-2011` or `2001-May-11` or even `1901-May-11`. I suppose you are using the `Month/Day/Year` format but I could be wrong.
- It's also easier to use `<=` and `<` instead of `BETWEEN` for date range checks:

  ```
  SELECT Customers.CustomerID
       , Customers.Company_Name
       , SUM(Orders.Total_Payment_Received) AS Total_Amount_of_Business
  FROM Customers
      JOIN Orders 
          ON Customers.CustomerID = Order.CustomerID
  WHERE Customers.LastModified >= '2011-01-01' 
    AND Customers.LastModified < '2011-05-16' 
  GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID ;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is:
You need to use a subquery similar to this.

```
SELECT 
    CustomerID, 
    (SELECT SUM(Total_Payment_Received) Total FROM Orders WHERE Orders.CustomerId=Customers.CustomerId) Total 
FROM Customers
```